# Why when I restart a pod in Kubernetes does the service I have in my container go down?

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I have created a pod with an apache service inside, and when I restart a node the services that are inside my pods are automatically deactivated and I have to activate them again manually with the /etc/init.d/apache2 start command. I don't know why this error happens and what can I do to solve it

Comment: There aren't usually "services" inside of pods, and if you need `kubectl exec` to manually start something (ever) your image is probably misconfigured.  (In some contexts Pods can get deleted or restarted outside your control; for your specific example, a cluster autoscaler can delete a Node and its Pods will need to be recreated, for example.)  Do you have a [mcve] demonstrating an image where this is a problem?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add command and args in your pod definition that start apache in foreground:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: podname
spec:
  containers:
  - name: containername
    image: yourimage
    command: ["apachectl"]
    args: ["-D", "FOREGROUND"]
  restartPolicy: OnFailure
```